# Why are the Color3 Values changing to the wrong number?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am working on making it to where players can make a cusotom, but when it sets the Color3 Value it changes to a number way bigger than normal parameters. For example, when then script trys to set the value to (255,0,0) it goes to (65025, 0, 0). Here is the code, what am I doing wrong?

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local Player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
    print("CustomChanged")
    if script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(0,0,0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,255,255)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,255,255) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,0,0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,0,0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255, 136, 0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255, 136, 0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,255,0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,255,0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(0,255,0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(0,255,0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(0,255,255)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(0,255,255) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(0,0,255)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(0,0,255) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,0,255)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,0,255) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,0,205)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,0,205) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(0,0,0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)` instead.

If you use `Color3.new(...)` it expects color values ranging from 0 to 1.

So since in the explorer it shows you 255 times that value, you would see 255 * 255 = 65025.

*By the way:*

If you want to avoid repeating the same code for each color, you could do something like this:

```
-- store all colors that you want to use in an array
local colors = {
    Color3.fromRGB(0,0,0),
    Color3.fromRGB(255,255,255),
    Color3.fromRGB(255,0,0),
    Color3.fromRGB(0,255,0),
    Color3.fromRGB(0,0,255)
}

-- keep track of current color
currentColor = 1

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if (currentColor == #colors) then                           -- it current color is the last one in the array, go back to zero
        currentColor = 0
    end
    currentColor = currentColor + 1                             -- increment current color by one

    script.Parent.BackgroundColor3 = colors[currentColor]       -- (here you do whatever you want to do with the color)
end)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Color3.FromRGB` instead of `Color3.new`. `Color3.new` goes from 0 to 1
and `Color3.FromRGB` goes from 0 to 255.
And if you're too lazy to use replace here's the script:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local Player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
    print("CustomChanged")
    if script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(0,0,0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,255,255)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,255,255) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,0,0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,0,0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255, 136, 0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255, 136, 0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,255,0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,255,0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(0,255,0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(0,255,0) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(0,255,255)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(0,255,255) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(0,0,255)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(0,0,255) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,0,255)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,0,255) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(255,0,205)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    elseif script.Parent.Value.Value == Color3.new(255,0,205) then
        script.Parent.Value.Value = Color3.new(0,0,0)
        Player.Skins.Custom.Head.Color.Value = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Custom.Head.Color = script.Parent.Value.Value
        script.Parent.Frame.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.Value.Value
    end
end)
```

Comment: I'm so sorry please upvote